# Model passed to the view is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My controller

```
public PartialViewResult AllMetalStockItems()
{
  var allMetalDtos = this.metalStockRepository.GetAllMetalSotckDtos();
  var allMetalViewModels = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MetalStockDto>,IEnumerable<MetalStockViewModel>>(allMetalDtos);
  return PartialView("_AllMetalStockItems",allMetalViewModels);
}
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<GlassContract.Models.ViewModels.Warehouse.MetalStockViewModel>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Metal Id
    </th>
    <th>
        Colour Code
    </th>
    <th>
        Length
    </th>
    <th>
        Quantity In Stock
    </th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.MetalId </td>
        <td>@item.ColorCode </td>
        <td>@item.Length </td>
        <td>@item.QuantityInStock </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I get the following message

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>  
>   Line 18:     @foreach (var item in @Model)

Here is the CreateMap

```
 public static void ConfigureMetalStockMapping()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<MetalStockDto, MetalStock>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<MetalStock, MetalStockDto>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<MetalStockViewModel, MetalStockDto>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<MetalStockDto, MetalStockViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<MetalStockDto>, IEnumerable<MetalStockViewModel>>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<MetalStockViewModel>, IEnumerable<MetalStockDto>>();
    }
```

`metalStockRepository.GetAllMetalSotckDtos()` works fine and the tests also pass with no issues. I'm using Automapper to map.

Comment: `allMetalViewModels` must be `null` so the mapping is not working. Can you post both the `MetalStockDto` and `MetalStockViewModel` models

Comment: After mapping did you check the model value is containing value ?

Comment: That't the other problem . When I set a breakpoint there, it never stops there. Straight away goes to the error.

Comment: Can you please post your `CreateMap` code for `IEnumerable<MetalStockDto>` to `IEnumerable<MetalStockViewModel>` ?

Comment: Please find the edited question with the Mapper

Answer (score 1):

I realized that

```
@Html.Partial("_AllMetalStockItems")
```

Doesn't call controller + action
I changed it to

```
@Html.Action("AllMetalStockItems","MetalStock")
```

and that solved my issue.  Thanks for the efforts and I have to apologise for not posting the view that has this code bit.